# .html() method and AJAX

Tags: jquery

Using the `.ajax()` method, I am trying to access an image thumbnail but I am struggling with the .html() method. I have tried using `.attr('src', URL)` and that seems to work, but it does not work with the  tag in my html. The code line `#imageLinkjust` is not working. Any suggestions?

```
$.ajax({
      url: "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=" + userInput,
      type: "GET",
   }).then(
      (data) => {
         // console.log(data);
         $('#bookTitle').html(data.items[0].volumeInfo.title);
         $('#authors').html('by ' + data.items[0].volumeInfo.authors);
         $('#imageLink').html('<img href= "data.items[0].volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail" />');
```

And here is the html:

```
<dl class="book-info">
      <dd id="bookTitle"></dd>
      <dd id="authors"></dd>
      <dd id="imageLink"></dd>
 </dl>
```

Comment: What does "it does not work" mean? Describe what you expect to happen and what happens instead. Are there any errors on the debug console? What does the rendered html look like?

Comment: And where the userInput come from?

Answer (score 1):

The variable is in quotes and is not being parsed. Try this

```
$('#imageLink').html(`<img src="${data.items[0].volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail}" />`);
```

Comment: Awesome, this worked perfectly. Thank you!